# How to express LEFT JOIN when 2 entities are linked by a navigation properties

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

Let say I have these 2 Entities

```
public class Product
{
   //..
   public ICollection<Photo> Photos { get; set; }
          = new List<Photo>();
}

public class Photo
{
  //..
  public PageLocation PageLocation { get; set; }
  public int ProductId { get; set; }
  public Product Product { get; set; }
}
```

I use this code to select a list of products. Each of them will associated with an image given the location where the product will be displayed.

```
var productList = GetAll().Include(p => p.PhotoImages)
        .Where(p =>
               p.PhotoImages.Any(
                     i => i.PageLocation == PageLocation.Home_Slider));
```

The problem is that when a product has no image for that location, then the product is not selected.

[Every examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/perform-left-outer-joins) that I've seen on left join show how to use 2 sources. In my case, I don't need 2 sources because I've a navigation property between Product and Image.

Is there a way to accomplish a left join without having to use 2 sources data? Something like this

```
SELECT *
FROM [dbo].[Products] p
LEFT JOIN 
(
  SELECT *
  FROM [dbo].[PhotoImages] 
  WHERE PageLocation = 1
 )img
ON p.Id = img.ProductId
```

Thanks for helping

Comment: the SQL query that is generated with the include is a left join. Your problem is that you don't want all related data, but only a subset of all matching tuples. Filtering of included tuples is currently not supported in EF's .Include().

Comment: You asked for products *with images* whose location is `home_slider`, not products without images or only home_sliders.

Comment: Please tag the appropriate EF version.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to accomplish a left join without having to use 2 sources data?

I don't think there is. In your SQL query you are joining with a new set, not the photos related to your products.

I believe that the best you can do is something like this:

```
var q = from prod in ctx.Products.Include(p => p.Photos) 
        join img in (
            from ph in ctx.Photos where ph.PageLocation == 1 select new { ph.ProductId, PageLocation = (int?)ph.PageLocation }
        ) on prod.Id equals img.ProductId into pjoin
        from pj in pjoin.DefaultIfEmpty()
        select new { prod, photo = pj, pj.PageLocation };

foreach (var p in q)
{
     Console.WriteLine($"{p.prod.Id} - {p.photo} - {p.PageLocation}");
}
```

EDIT: There is only one join in this query, as can be seen from the generated SQL:

```
SELECT 
[Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
[Extent1].[Name] AS [Name], 
[Extent2].[PageLocation] AS [PageLocation], 
[Extent2].[ProductId] AS [ProductId]
FROM  [dbo].[Product] AS [Extent1]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Photo] AS [Extent2] ON (1 = [Extent2].[PageLocation]) AND ([Extent1].[Id] = [Extent2].[ProductId])
```

Comment: I thought using 2 sources will have adverse consequences to performance. That's why I've avoided so far any linq query related to 2 or more sources.

Comment: There's only one join, and the generated SQL is almost the same as yours. See my edit.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you use the navigation property EF will generate a SQL statement that has an `inner join` though.

> **How Navigation property works**
>
> When we apply navigation property in our code, it means we are asking EF to  automatically perform a join between the two tables.

*source:* [Navigation Property With Code First (Navigation Property In EF)](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/navigation-property-with-code-first-navigation-property-in-ef/)

So you could use the example you already found on [MS docs - Perform left outer joins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/perform-left-outer-joins) - to realize your query. Your SQL example has two sources too. First `Products` table and as second the `PhotoImages` table or I misunderstood what you mean.

An approach for your query could be:

```
var products = (
    from p in _context.Products
    join pi in _context.PhotoImages on p.Id equals pi.ProductId
    into productsWithImages

    from pwi in productsWithImages.Where(pwi => pwi.PageLocation == 1).DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new ExtendedProduct
    {
        p.Id,
        p.Name,
        photoId = (int?)pwi.Id,
        pwi.PageLocation,
        pwi.Url
    }
)
```

Comment: That's just a blog post, you can't use it as a source and claim `Include` performs inner joins. If it did, you wouldn't be able to load root entities without children even if no `Where` existed. Something that is obviously wrong

Comment: Thanks, was my fault and I removed it, because it was not explained enough from my side. As far as I know `Include` works internally with `CASE WHEN` and sets a flag if a `join` should be executed or not. Therefore it works for your mentioned case. Well, it is a blog post, but after own tries and experience I can confirm that behavior for navigation properties and like described `Include`. But I will do some more researches for better sources. Thanks for the hint.